# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable - class coding

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

I am trying to code a class, in python.  I think the answer to my question is probably very simple but i am new to code here is the code:

[The Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3yuh.png)

[Once run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKw2n.png)

I dont see anything wrong, is there something simple i have missed?

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as image. Just share the raw text in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

the method name and the list name both are actions. when its initialized self.actions ( method) is replaced by self.actions (list). list is not callable

```
class Troll:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.phrases = ['Pass the ball','SHOOT']
        self.available_actions = ['passes the ball','shoots']
    def speak(self):
        print(self.name, "shouts", random.choice(self.phrases))
    def actions(self):
        print(self.name,"decides to", self.available_actions)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case method name overrides variable name because both are same. So either change method name or variable name.